# Is P-Trap installed correctly?

Tags: plumbing, drain, smell, p-trap

Our bathroom sink is used multiple times per day but there is a bad odor almost every time we turn on the water, coming from p trap. We have found some bad DIY work in this house already, so I’m wondering if this trap is installed correctly.

[image]

Comment: I think you have the same issue as https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/240049/is-my-p-trap-installed-correctly

Comment: The simple fix here is to add an air admittance valve above where the P attaches to the drain and becomes an S. Just tee the wall pipe for the P and put the AAV at the very top.

Comment: @Machavity Don't those usually have a height requirement? Without seeing how much room is between the drain elbow and the bottom of the sink I feel like that's not great advice to be giving.

Answer (score 7):

This is not the correct way to install a p-trap. The pipe exiting the sink should run vertically into the top of the p-trap, then exit the p-trap horizontally back into the wall and connect to the sanitary pipe via a sanitary tee fitting.

The configuration in your photo converts the p-trap into an s-trap. S-traps are known to fail due to self-siphoning. Your configuration also eliminates the proper venting of the drain line, which can cause slower draining of the sink.
[image]

Unfortunately, it looks like you would need to open up the wall to remove the 90° elbow and reconfigure the piping so that the drain line is horizontal.

Comment: The "proper venting" is exactly what "prevents siphoning."

Comment: Technically, the trap installation is just fine. It's the drain stack that has problems.